# Paypal Rest Subscription Notification on user charge?

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

Im currently building my apps using paypal rest api.

If i create a subscription. I receive a webhook that the billing.subscription was created.

How i understood it... Paypal will only notify me next time when the subscription was canceled. Which is ok for me. But how can i check at the end of each payment cycle that the subscription was paid ? I have to create invoices for my customets and i really want to avoid to create invoices that wont get paid ever because of me not un derstanding how to check these recurring payments. Hope someone can help me out.

Is there a way to check if the subscription was paid \ is there a way to get a notification if the charge from the subscription succeeds

Cheers and thank you guys

Comment: Welcome to the site! I suggest you take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask